# Editor in same column as terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode, how do I create a heterogeneous vertical split contained completely within a single column? I would like to define a column such that the terminal is on top, a text editor is on the bottom, and neither this terminal nor this editor intrudes into the other columns. Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be very easy with vscode1.58, due out this week.  Because you can drag a terminal to the editor area.

First create your vertical split so you have two columns.  Then just drag a terminal into the upper half of the right-hand split.  Then close your Panel (where the terminal was).

[image: put terminal into right-hand column]

Also there are some move the terminal commands you can make keybindings out of:

[image: move terminal commands]

See more https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_58.md#terminals-in-the-editor-area